# @ContentChildren not picking up items inside custom component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-decorator

I'm trying to use `@ContentChildren` to pick up all items with the `#buttonItem` tag.

```
@ContentChildren('buttonItem', { descendants: true })
```

This works when we have the ref item directly in the parent component.

```
<!-- @ContentChildren returns child item -->
<parent-component>
  <button #buttonItem></button>
<parent-component>
```

But, if the element with the `#buttonItem` ref is wrapped in a custom component, that does not get picked by the `@ContentChildren` even when I set the `{descendants: true}` option.

```
<!-- @ContentChildren returns empty -->
<parent-component>
  <child-component-with-button-ref></child-component-with-button-ref>
<parent-component>
```

I have created a simple [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vygojm) demonstrating this.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16299 looks like active limitation

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I wanted to get a list of highlightable items in a popup so that keyboard navigation can be enabled. I was going to mark the highlightable with an element ref.

I have a sample stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-popup-child-selection-issue

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't appear to be a timeline for a resolution of this item via github... I also found a comment stating you cannot query across an ng-content boundary.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14320#issuecomment-278228336

Below is possible workaround to get the elements to bubble up from the `OptionPickerComponent`.

---

[image]

---

in `OptionPickerComponent` count `#listItem` there and emit the array `AfterContentInit`

```
 @Output() grandchildElements = new EventEmitter();     
 @ViewChildren('listItem') _items

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.grandchildElements.emit(this._items)
    })
  }
```

Set template reference `#picker`, register to `(grandchildElements)` event and set the `$event` to `picker.grandchildElements`

```
 <app-option-picker #picker [optionList]="[1, 2, 3]" (grandchildElements)="picker.grandchildElements = $event" popup-content>
```

Create Input on `PopupComponent` to accept values from `picker.grandchildElements`

```
@Input('grandchildElements') grandchildElements: any
```

In `app.component.html` accept `picker.grandchildElements` to the input

```
<app-popup [grandchildElements]="picker.grandchildElements">
```

`popup.component` set `console.log` for open and close

```
open() {
    if (this.grandchildElements) {
      console.log(this.grandchildElements);
    }
    else {
      console.log(this.childItems);
    }

 close() {
     if (this.grandchildElements) {
      console.log(this.grandchildElements);
    }
    else {
      console.log(this.childItems);
    }
```

`popup.component` change your `ContentChildren` back to `listItem`

```
@ContentChildren('listItem', { descendants: true }) childItems: Element;
```

`popup.component.html` set header expression

```
<h3>Child Items: {{grandchildElements ? grandchildElements.length : childItems.length}}</h3>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-popup-child-selection-issue-bjhjds?embed=1&file=src/app/option-picker/option-picker.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. We are using Kendo Components for angular. It is required to define Columns as ContentChilds of the Grid component. When I wanted to wrap it into a custom component and tried to provide additional columns via ng-content it simply didn't work.

I managed to get it working by resetting the QueryList of the grid component AfterViewInit of the custom wrapping component.

```
  @ViewChild(GridComponent, { static: true })
  public grid: GridComponent;

  @ContentChildren(ColumnBase)
  columns: QueryList<ColumnBase>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.grid.columns.reset([...this.grid.columns.toArray(), ...this.columns.toArray()]);
    this.grid.columnList = new ColumnList(this.grid.columns);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is re-binding to the content child.

In the template where you are adding the content child you want picked up:

```
<outer-component>
  <content-child [someBinding]="true" (onEvent)="someMethod($event)">
      e.g. inner text content
  </content-child>
</outer-component>
```

And inside of the example fictional `<outer-component>`:

```
@Component()
class OuterComponent {
  @ContentChildren(ContentChild) contentChildren: QueryList<ContentChild>;
}
```

and the template for `<outer-component>` adding the `<content-child>` component, re-binding to it:

```
<inner-template>
  <content-child
    *ngFor="let child of contentChildren?.toArray()"
    [someBinding]="child.someBinding"
    (onEvent)="child.onEvent.emit($event)"
  >
      <!--Here you'll have to get the inner text somehow-->
  </content-child>
</inner-template>
```

Getting that inner text could be impossible depending on your case. If you have full control over the fictional `<content-child>` component you could expose access to the element ref:

```
@Component()
class ContentChildComponent {
  constructor(public element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>)
}
```

And then when you're rebinding to it, you can add the `[innerHTML]` binding:

```
<content-child
  *ngFor="let child of contentChildren?.toArray()"
  [someBinding]="child.someBinding"
  (onEvent)="child.onEvent.emit($event)"
  [innerHTML]="child.element.nativeElement.innerHTML"
></content-child>
```

You may have to [sanitize the input](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to `[innerHTML]` however.